# How to set turtlebot to point to some orientation when it arrives?

Tags: navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**how to set the turtlebot point or not point to a specific orientation when it arrives the goal?**

I'm using rviz to set the goal for my mova_base for Turtlebot.

How to **configure the amcl files or something others** to make the turtlebot point or not point to the specific orientation when it arrives the goal.

Thanks!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228502/how-to-set-turtlebot-to-point-to-some-orientation-when-it-arrives?/) by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2016-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you set the goal point in rviz, it is an arrow. The turtlebot will point in the direction of that arrow when it arrives at the destination.

If you hold the mouse button while setting the destination in rviz, you can change the direction of the arrow. The goal is not sent until you release the mouse button.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**This is the snapshot on the book "ROS by Example_Hydro_Vol1". The answer is in it. Enjoy!**

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) with karma: 287 on 2016-03-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1